# QGIS how to improve triggers on SQL - SpatiaLite

Tags: qgis, sql, spatialite, trigger

I'm looking for a way to improve the way my triggers are working on a SpatiaLite layer.
Currently, it takes 45 seconds to work on 1000 entities. Is there a way to improve the performance?

My triggers are doing this :
[After insert or the update]

UPDATE CORINE_1 with the correspondence of EUNIS_1, in the DATABASE "HABREF", field "EUNIS12-CORINE" ; same for CORINE_2, CORINE_3, CORINE_4.

UPDATE EUNIS22_1 with the correspondence of EUNIS_1, in the DATABASE "HABREF", field "EUNIS12-EUNIS22" ; same for EUNIS22_2, EUNIS22_3, EUNIS22_4.

UPDATE HIC_1 with the correspondence of EUNIS_1, in the DATABASE "HABREF", field "EUNIS12-HIP" ; same for HIC_2, HIC_3, HIC_4.

UPDATE ZH_1 with the correspondence of CORINE_1, in the DATABASE "HABREF", field "Zones humides" ; same for ZH_2, ZH_3, ZH_4.

Here are my current triggers:

> 

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_corine1
    AFTER INSERT ON HABITATS_POLY
    BEGIN
        UPDATE HABITATS_POLY
        SET CORINE_1 = (SELECT "EUNIS12-CORINE" FROM HABREF WHERE "EUNIS(2012)" = new.EUNIS_1)
        WHERE EUNIS_1 = new.EUNIS_1;
    END;
    CREATE TRIGGER update_corine1
    AFTER UPDATE OF EUNIS_1 ON HABITATS_POLY
    BEGIN
        UPDATE HABITATS_POLY
        SET CORINE_1 = (SELECT "EUNIS12-CORINE" FROM HABREF WHERE "EUNIS(2012)" = new.EUNIS_1)
        WHERE EUNIS_1 = new.EUNIS_1;
    END;
    CREATE TRIGGER insert_corine2
    AFTER INSERT ON HABITATS_POLY
    BEGIN
        UPDATE HABITATS_POLY
        SET CORINE_2 = (SELECT "EUNIS12-CORINE" FROM HABREF WHERE "EUNIS(2012)" = new.EUNIS_2)
        WHERE EUNIS_2 = new.EUNIS_2;
    END;
    CREATE TRIGGER update_corine2
    AFTER UPDATE OF EUNIS_2 ON HABITATS_POLY
    BEGIN
        UPDATE HABITATS_POLY
        SET CORINE_2 = (SELECT "EUNIS12-CORINE" FROM HABREF WHERE "EUNIS(2012)" = new.EUNIS_2)
        WHERE EUNIS_2 = new.EUNIS_2;
    END;
    CREATE TRIGGER insert_corine3
    AFTER INSERT ON HABITATS_POLY
    BEGIN
        UPDATE HABITATS_POLY
        SET CORINE_3 = (SELECT "EUNIS12-CORINE" FROM HABREF WHERE "EUNIS(2012)" = new.EUNIS_3)
        WHERE EUNIS_3 = new.EUNIS_3;
    END;
    CREATE TRIGGER update_corine3
    AFTER UPDATE OF EUNIS_3 ON HABITATS_POLY
    BEGIN
        UPDATE HABITATS_POLY
        SET CORINE_3 = (SELECT "EUNIS12-CORINE" FROM HABREF WHERE "EUNIS(2012)" = new.EUNIS_3)
        WHERE EUNIS_3 = new.EUNIS_3;
    END;
    CREATE TRIGGER insert_corine4
    AFTER INSERT ON HABITATS_POLY
    BEGIN
        UPDATE HABITATS_POLY
        SET CORINE_4 = (SELECT "EUNIS12-CORINE" FROM HABREF WHERE "EUNIS(2012)" = new.EUNIS_4)
        WHERE EUNIS_4 = new.EUNIS_4;
    END;
    CREATE TRIGGER update_corine4
    AFTER UPDATE OF EUNIS_4 ON HABITATS_POLY
    BEGIN
        UPDATE HABITATS_POLY
        SET CORINE_4 = (SELECT "EUNIS12-CORINE" FROM HABREF WHERE "EUNIS(2012)" = new.EUNIS_4)
        WHERE EUNIS_4 = new.EUNIS_4;
    END;
```

> 

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_corine1
    AFTER INSERT ON HABITATS_POLY
    BEGIN
        UPDATE HABITATS_POLY
        SET CORINE_1 = (SELECT "EUNIS12-CORINE" FROM HABREF WHERE "EUNIS(2012)" = new.EUNIS_1)
        WHERE EUNIS_1 = new.EUNIS_1;
    END;
    CREATE TRIGGER update_corine1
    AFTER UPDATE OF EUNIS_1 ON HABITATS_POLY
    BEGIN
        UPDATE HABITATS_POLY
        SET CORINE_1 = (SELECT "EUNIS12-CORINE" FROM HABREF WHERE "EUNIS(2012)" = new.EUNIS_1)
        WHERE EUNIS_1 = new.EUNIS_1;
    END;
    CREATE TRIGGER insert_corine2
    AFTER INSERT ON HABITATS_POLY
    BEGIN
        UPDATE HABITATS_POLY
        SET CORINE_2 = (SELECT "EUNIS12-CORINE" FROM HABREF WHERE "EUNIS(2012)" = new.EUNIS_2)
        WHERE EUNIS_2 = new.EUNIS_2;
    END;
    CREATE TRIGGER update_corine2
    AFTER UPDATE OF EUNIS_2 ON HABITATS_POLY
    BEGIN
        UPDATE HABITATS_POLY
        SET CORINE_2 = (SELECT "EUNIS12-CORINE" FROM HABREF WHERE "EUNIS(2012)" = new.EUNIS_2)
        WHERE EUNIS_2 = new.EUNIS_2;
    END;
    CREATE TRIGGER insert_corine3
    AFTER INSERT ON HABITATS_POLY
    BEGIN
        UPDATE HABITATS_POLY
        SET CORINE_3 = (SELECT "EUNIS12-CORINE" FROM HABREF WHERE "EUNIS(2012)" = new.EUNIS_3)
        WHERE EUNIS_3 = new.EUNIS_3;
    END;
    CREATE TRIGGER update_corine3
    AFTER UPDATE OF EUNIS_3 ON HABITATS_POLY
    BEGIN
        UPDATE HABITATS_POLY
        SET CORINE_3 = (SELECT "EUNIS12-CORINE" FROM HABREF WHERE "EUNIS(2012)" = new.EUNIS_3)
        WHERE EUNIS_3 = new.EUNIS_3;
    END;
    CREATE TRIGGER insert_corine4
    AFTER INSERT ON HABITATS_POLY
    BEGIN
        UPDATE HABITATS_POLY
        SET CORINE_4 = (SELECT "EUNIS12-CORINE" FROM HABREF WHERE "EUNIS(2012)" = new.EUNIS_4)
        WHERE EUNIS_4 = new.EUNIS_4;
    END;
    CREATE TRIGGER update_corine4
    AFTER UPDATE OF EUNIS_4 ON HABITATS_POLY
    BEGIN
        UPDATE HABITATS_POLY
        SET CORINE_4 = (SELECT "EUNIS12-CORINE" FROM HABREF WHERE "EUNIS(2012)" = new.EUNIS_4)
        WHERE EUNIS_4 = new.EUNIS_4;
    END;
```

> 

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_hic_1
AFTER INSERT ON HABITATS_POLY
BEGIN
    UPDATE HABITATS_POLY
    SET HIC_1 = (SELECT "EUNIS12-HIP" FROM HABREF WHERE "EUNIS(2012)" = new.EUNIS_1)
    WHERE EUNIS_1 = new.EUNIS_1;
END;
CREATE TRIGGER update_hic_1
AFTER UPDATE OF EUNIS_1 ON HABITATS_POLY
BEGIN
    UPDATE HABITATS_POLY
    SET HIC_1 = (SELECT "EUNIS12-HIP" FROM HABREF WHERE "EUNIS(2012)" = new.EUNIS_1)
    WHERE EUNIS_1 = new.EUNIS_1;
END;
CREATE TRIGGER insert_hic_2
AFTER INSERT ON HABITATS_POLY
BEGIN
    UPDATE HABITATS_POLY
    SET HIC_2 = (SELECT "EUNIS12-HIP" FROM HABREF WHERE "EUNIS(2012)" = new.EUNIS_2)
    WHERE EUNIS_2 = new.EUNIS_2;
END;
CREATE TRIGGER update_hic_2
AFTER UPDATE OF EUNIS_2 ON HABITATS_POLY
BEGIN
    UPDATE HABITATS_POLY
    SET HIC_2 = (SELECT "EUNIS12-HIP" FROM HABREF WHERE "EUNIS(2012)" = new.EUNIS_2)
    WHERE EUNIS_2 = new.EUNIS_2;
END;
CREATE TRIGGER insert_hic_3
AFTER INSERT ON HABITATS_POLY
BEGIN
    UPDATE HABITATS_POLY
    SET HIC_3 = (SELECT "EUNIS12-HIP" FROM HABREF WHERE "EUNIS(2012)" = new.EUNIS_3)
    WHERE EUNIS_3 = new.EUNIS_3;
END;
CREATE TRIGGER update_hic_3
AFTER UPDATE OF EUNIS_3 ON HABITATS_POLY
BEGIN
    UPDATE HABITATS_POLY
    SET HIC_3=  (SELECT "EUNIS12-HIP" FROM HABREF WHERE "EUNIS(2012)" = new.EUNIS_3)
    WHERE EUNIS_3 = new.EUNIS_3;
END;
CREATE TRIGGER insert_hic_4
AFTER INSERT ON HABITATS_POLY
BEGIN
    UPDATE HABITATS_POLY
    SET HIC_4 = (SELECT "EUNIS12-HIP" FROM HABREF WHERE "EUNIS(2012)" = new.EUNIS_4)
    WHERE EUNIS_4 = new.EUNIS_4;
END;
CREATE TRIGGER update_hic_4
AFTER UPDATE OF EUNIS_4 ON HABITATS_POLY
BEGIN
    UPDATE HABITATS_POLY
    SET HIC_4 =  (SELECT "EUNIS12-HIP" FROM HABREF WHERE "EUNIS(2012)" = new.EUNIS_4)
    WHERE EUNIS_4 = new.EUNIS_4;
END;
```

> 

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_ZH_1
AFTER INSERT ON HABITATS_POLY
BEGIN
    UPDATE HABITATS_POLY
    SET ZH_1 = (SELECT "Zones humides" FROM HABREF WHERE "Code CORINE" = new.CORINE_1)
    WHERE CORINE_1 = new.CORINE_1;
END;
CREATE TRIGGER update_ZH_1
AFTER UPDATE OF CORINE_1 ON HABITATS_POLY
BEGIN
    UPDATE HABITATS_POLY
    SET ZH_1 = (SELECT "Zones humides" FROM HABREF WHERE "Code CORINE" = new.CORINE_1)
    WHERE CORINE_1 = new.CORINE_1;
END;
CREATE TRIGGER insert_ZH_2
AFTER INSERT ON HABITATS_POLY
BEGIN
    UPDATE HABITATS_POLY
    SET ZH_2 = (SELECT "Zones humides" FROM HABREF WHERE "Code CORINE" = new.CORINE_2)
    WHERE CORINE_2 = new.CORINE_2;
END;
CREATE TRIGGER update_ZH_2
AFTER UPDATE OF CORINE_2 ON HABITATS_POLY
BEGIN
    UPDATE HABITATS_POLY
    SET ZH_2 = (SELECT "Zones humides" FROM HABREF WHERE "Code CORINE" = new.CORINE_2)
    WHERE CORINE_2 = new.CORINE_2;
END;
CREATE TRIGGER insert_ZH_3
AFTER INSERT ON HABITATS_POLY
BEGIN
    UPDATE HABITATS_POLY
    SET ZH_3 = (SELECT "Zones humides" FROM HABREF WHERE "Code CORINE" = new.CORINE_3)
    WHERE CORINE_3 = new.CORINE_3;
END;
CREATE TRIGGER update_ZH_3
AFTER UPDATE OF CORINE_3 ON HABITATS_POLY
BEGIN
    UPDATE HABITATS_POLY
    SET ZH_3 =  (SELECT "Zones humides" FROM HABREF WHERE "Code CORINE" = new.CORINE_3)
    WHERE CORINE_3 = new.CORINE_3;
END;
CREATE TRIGGER insert_ZH_4
AFTER INSERT ON HABITATS_POLY
BEGIN
    UPDATE HABITATS_POLY
    SET ZH_4 = (SELECT "Zones humides" FROM HABREF WHERE "Code CORINE" = new.CORINE_4)
    WHERE CORINE_4 = new.CORINE_4;
END;
CREATE TRIGGER update_ZH_4
AFTER UPDATE OF CORINE_4 ON HABITATS_POLY
BEGIN
    UPDATE HABITATS_POLY
    SET ZH_4 =  (SELECT "Zones humides" FROM HABREF WHERE "Code CORINE" = new.CORINE_4)
    WHERE CORINE_4 = new.CORINE_4;
END;
```

Comment: Don't update the entire table but only the rows that were initially updated,(`update .. set .. where .. and id=new.id`)

Comment: I am not sure to understand. Isn't it what it is already doing ? When I use AFTER UPDATE OF EUNIS_1 ON HABITATS_POLY, the whole table is updated (column EUNIS_1) because of one change ? 

Can I do it this way?
CREATE TRIGGER update_corine1
AFTER UPDATE OF EUNIS_1 ON HABITATS_POLY
BEGIN
    UPDATE HABITATS_POLY
    SET CORINE_1 = (SELECT "EUNIS12-CORINE" FROM HABREF WHERE "EUNIS(2012)" = new.EUNIS_1)
    WHERE EUNIS_1 = new.EUNIS_1
    AND CORINE_1 IS DISTINCT FROM (SELECT "EUNIS12-CORINE" FROM HABREF WHERE "EUNIS(2012)" = new.EUNIS_1);
END;

Comment: no, it's not doing it. Ex with the last trigger: you set the value of `CORINE_4` of records `id=1`, then the trigger updates every records in the table having the same `CORINE_4`. If you add the `id=new.id` condition to the where clause, only the same row will be updated. With your comment above, other rows could still be updated (maybe not, depends on the data)